# d3 conditional append on the fly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around D3 and now I wan't to create a custom select widget.

I have some list of categories.

I wan't to put first categories in single line, and if some doesn't fit, put them in a dropdown.

So idea is to put some part in one region and other in another region, while computing occupied space on the fly when adding elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas for what? This should be fairly straightforward to implement.

Comment: The straight forward approach is that I can select some element and append collection of data, but what I want is to append only until enough space and then to append to different parent.

Comment: You could precompute how much space each element will take and partition the data based on that.